# SQL column added twice during INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am trying to join two tables from a database; `energyImport` and `sunAlt`.

`energyImport` has three columns: `timestamp_id`, `energy`, `duration`.

`sunAlt` has two columns: `timestamp_id`, `altitude`

I am doing an inner join on these two tables using the SQL:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM energyImport
INNER JOIN sunAz ON sunAz.timestamp_id = energyImport.timestamp_id;
```

The output from this is:

```
timestamp_id,duration,energy,timestamp_id,altitude
1601769600,1800,81310,1601769600,0.0
1601771400,1800,78915,1601771400,0.0
1601773200,1800,78305,1601773200,0.0
```

The problem is that the `timestamp_id` column is repeated. How can I join these columns and only include the first `timestamp_id`?

Comment: Instead of selecting all columns with `select *`, list the columns that you want to see in the order you want to see them. It is also advisable to use table aliases, e.g. `FROM energyimport ie`, and then use these: `select ie.timestamp_id, ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the * with

```
energyImport.timestamp_id,energyImport.duration, energyImport.energy,
sunAz.altitude
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you specify the columns that you want in the results:

```
SELECT e.timestamp_id, e.duration, e.energy, s.altitude 
FROM energyImport e INNER JOIN sunAz s
ON s.timestamp_id = e.timestamp_id;
```

Or, use `NATURAL` instead of `INNER` join, so that the join is based on the columns(s) with the same names of the 2 tables (if this fits your requirement), because `NATURAL` join returns only 1 of each pair of these columns:

```
SELECT *
FROM energyImport NATURAL JOIN sunAz;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7793a20bef56475b70552df7d9723463).

Comment: My advice: Never ever use natural joins. If someone happens to add columns to the tables later (e.g. give all table a last_updated_at column), then existing queries with natural joins will break. I.e. they still run, but return incorrect results. Natural joins should never have been invented in my opinion.

Comment: What you can do though is joining with the `USING` clause: `FROM energyImport e INNER JOIN sunAz s USING (timestamp_id)` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=ce285942a8e890987d6d9a05808f5e26. But my recommendation is to simply go with the first suggestion and exlicitly  list the columns you want to select.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - That was what I was looking for, although I understand your point about the explicit listing and will probably do this.